# Apply tag on Managed RG while deploying Synapse Workspace using Bicep

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-bicep

I am using the bicep template as provided in the below doc. While creating workspace, it also creates Azure Managed RG and I am providing name for it from parameters. Can we apply tags to this RG? What should be the change in Bicep template?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.synapse/workspaces?tabs=bicep

Answer (score 0):

You can just add them to your workspaces resource.

```
 tags: {
tagName1: 'tagValue1'
tagName2: 'tagValue2'
  }
```

You can see how it fits into the template in the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.synapse/workspaces?tabs=bicep

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. The bicep template is applying tag on resource and managed RG as well.

Deployment was failing with tags error due policy set which needed some mandatory tags.